# Joint js how to align text to the left of a rect object

Tags: javascript, jointjs

im drawing a diagram using joint js, so, im creating some rect objects with a text inside but i need to align that text to the left:

```
var rectname = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            position: { x: 110, y: y_value },
            size: { width: 450, height: 45 },
            attrs: { 
                rect: { fill: bgcolor2,'stroke-width': 0 },
                text: {
                    text: 'Any text here',
                    fill: 'white'
                }
            }
        });
```

I already tried this text properties like this but it doesnt work :

```
var rectname = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            position: { x: 110, y: y_value },
            size: { width: 450, height: 45 },
            attrs: { 
                rect: { fill: bgcolor2,'stroke-width': 0 },
                text: {
                    text: 'Any text here',
                    fill: 'white'
                    'ref-x': .5, 
                    'ref-y': .5, 
                    ref: 'rect', 
                    'y-alignment': 'middle', 
                    'x-alignment': 'left'
                }
            }
        });
```

And also tried settting both x and y alignment in 'middle' without results.

Any idea please ?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the label to set the text of the element and use 'text-anchor' property to set the text alignment as below

```
var rectname = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 110, y: y_value },
        size: { width: 450, height: 45 },
        attrs: {
            '.label': {text: 'Any text here', 'text-anchor': 'end'}
        }
    });
```

More info on text-anchor property can be found here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried what you said but now it doesn't show any text at all =(

Comment: Think i found it, not as that but you gave me an idea, so i vote you up. Thanks again!

Comment: You found it. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To the next interested dev:

I had multiline strings, so jointjs would center each of them (not cool). My solution:

```
text: { text: code, fill: 'gray', fontSize: fontSize, fontFamily, 'text-anchor': 'left', 'ref-x': borderSize / 2 }
```

At that point, I already knew calculated the required width and just added a border.